# Transition isn't working in css

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am creating a dropdown-menu. Everything is working so far. The one thing that isn't working is the change in opacity when the dropdown-menu appears. I also wanted to add a flow in height. I mean the whole height should appear build itself up after 0.5sec.

Now I thought I might achieve these things with transition, but somehow it isn't working at all.

```
#nav-primary ul ul{
    position:absolute; 
    left:0px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition:opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index:497;
}

#nav-primary ul li:hover > ul { 
    opacity: 1; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:100%; 
    left:0; 
 }
```

Basically I am using the wp_nav_menu from wordpress:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu', 
                    'link_before' => '<span>',
                    'link_after' => '</span>',) );
```

The structure should be as follows:

```
ul ...                         // main-menu
    li ...
        ul ...                 // sub-menu
            li ...
                <a>
                <span>
                </a>
```

Comment: you have the transition on `ul ul` but the `:hover` takes place on an `li`

Comment: thanks for the remark. I have changed it now. Now the opacity wont change. The dropdown-menu stays transparent. Why is that?

Comment: can you provide your HTML so I can see your setup OR look at this site `http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337` which has some dropdown menu fade ins

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS code, you never apply any positioning to the top-most parent ul element. Maybe that's a typo?

Your first line is:

```
#nav-primary ul ul{
```

but maybe you meant:

```
#nav-primary ul {
```

Your best first step would be to set up your parent ul. Without positioning properties on your parent ul and li's your child li's won't know what they're positioning against.

Assuming you have some other default styles in place, something like this is all you would need:

```
#nav-primary ul {
    position:relative; 
}
```

Combine that with some of what you already have, and some other basic styles, and you're on your way:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #aaa;
}

ul li li {
    background: #ccc;
}

#nav-primary ul {
    position:relative;
}

#nav-primary ul > li > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    transition:opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

#nav-primary ul > li:hover > ul { 
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonthomas/27Ymw/1/

Hope that helps!